# Want to create a pine script for trading view

Tags: pine-script, indicator

Want to create a pine script for creating an indicator which draws horizontal lines based on the "historic value" for previous day open candle value. And it should create lines based on the formula

value= (SQRT("prev day open")+9)^3

Please send me pine script for creating such horizontal lines based on the given condition.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to you, that you get familiar to the Pine Script language reference, where you can search these things up

[short tutorial in tradingvies pine editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xebl5.png)

your wanted variable would look like that

```
value = math.pow(math.sqrt(open[1]) + 9, 3) //open[1] previous bar open
```

To print or display horizontal lines on a certain condition you can do that as follows:

```
if condition
   line.new(x1, y1, x2, y2) //you can look for help in the reference
```

keep in mind that tradingview has [limitations](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/writing/Limitations.html?highlight=line%20limitation#line-box-and-label-limits) on how many bars a line can go back, and how much there can be on a chart

Comment: Could you please tell how to define the values of x1,y1.....?                                                           And how to draw horizontal lines of limited length ( upto one day only), and with variable values which have been calculated earlier ?

Comment: Well, that depends on how you want to do it. You could send me a screenshot, of how exactly you want to have your line.

Usually you use `bar_index`, for `x1` And `x2`